# sed - unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, sed

I have this peace of code:

```
cat BP.csv | while read line ; do
    goterm=$(awk '{print $1}') ;
    name=$(awk '{print $2}') ;
    grep -w "$goterm" GOEA.csv | sed "s/$goterm/pi/g" ;
done
```

file `BP.csv` has this format:

```
GO:0008283  cell proliferation
GO:0009405  pathogenesis
GO:0010201  response to continuous far red light stimulus by the high-irradiance response system
GO:0009641  shade avoidance
```

while `GOEA.csv` has this format:

```
4577    GO:0006807  0.994   2014_06_01
4577    GO:0016788  0.989   2014_06_01
4577    GO:0043169  0.977   2014_06_01
4577    GO:0043170  0.963   2014_06_01
```

`sed` doesn't work. I want to change `GO:0043170` for example, to string "pi", but it gives:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
```

Why?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of goterm?

Comment: @Avinash Raj, really? Can't you see that goterm is first column of file BP.csv?

Comment: Ick, you do realise those two `awk` commands are both reading from `stdin`, not from the `$line` variable, right?

Comment: @Debasis, really you ask that?

Comment: @ams is right as your `awk` in particular looks faulty. Whole script can be re-written in awk itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You running your `awk` command against no input, Try this:

```
cat BP.csv | while read line ; do
    goterm=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$line") ;
    name=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$line" ) ;
    grep -w "$goterm" GOEA.csv | sed "s/$goterm/pi/g" ;
done
```

Comment: +1. awk was actually run against stdin, so `$goterm` contained a line feed separated list of the first column values from line 2 and onwards. Since the `s` expression then had an unescaped literal line feed in the middle, sed said it was unterminated.

Comment: @thatotherguy you're right, otherwise awk would hang waiting for input.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clean up this code a bit:

```
while read goterm name
do
    grep -w "$goterm" GOEA.csv | sed "s/$goterm/pi/g"
done < BP.cvs
```

The problem is that your awk statements are attempting to read in from STDIN just like your `while` is doing. You're reading from the same input stream.

What you want to do is to pull out the values from your line. I'm using `read` to do this. The `read` statement uses the values in `$IFS` to separate out the input. This is normally spaces, tabs, and newlines. The `read` reads each variable you put on the line, and the last value read in contains the entire rest of the line.

Thus:

```
while read line
```

reads in the entire line while:

```
while goterm name
```

will break the line as

```
goterm="GO:0008283"
name="cell proliferation"
```

One more thing. When you use `grep` and `sed` together, you probably can get away with just `sed`:

```
while read goterm name
do
    sed -n "/$goterm/s/$goterm/pi/gp" GOEA.csv
done < BP.csv
```

The format for the sed command is:

```
/lines/command/parameters/
```

So, I'm searching for lines with `$goterm` in them, then I am replacing `$goterm` with `pi`. The `-n` means don't print out the lines as sed processes them and `p` means to print out the lines were the substitute is located.

By the way, `csv` as a file suffix means *comma separated values* but neither file looks like it is comma separated. Are these tabs separating each field. If so, you'll need to modify `$IFS` to be tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure that whole thing more like this:

```
while read goterm restofline
do
  grep -w "${goterm}" GOEA.csv | sed -e "s/${goterm}/pi/g"
done < BP.csv
```

No reason for the `awk` things, as the `bash` `read` builtin will do rudimentary field splitting for you if you give it multiple variables. Also, you aren't using `name` anyway, so it's not needed. `cat` is unnecessary as well.

Depending on your exact use case, even the `grep` may be unnecessary, making the inner command simply `sed -ne "s/${goterm}/pi/gp" GOEA.csv`. Unless your purpose for the `grep -w` is eliminating lines where `${goterm}` is a substring of a word instead of the whole word...

For future reference, inserting a `set -x` above your loop in your script would show you the exact commands that are being run, so that you can compare them with your expectations.